# need to call a function which uses 'this' outside of the main activity in Android

Tags: java, android, this

This is the error I get when I try this call from an outside class. Thanks in Advance.

### Function Call

```
GuessingLettersActivity.userGuess();
```

### Error

Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method userGuess() from the type GuessingLettersActivity

### Function in Main Activity (GuessingLettersActivity)

```
public  void userGuess()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle("Enter A Guess");
    alert.setMessage("Enter your guess below. Just enter the letter or symbol. It is case sensitive!");

    // Set an EditText view to get user input 
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    alert.setView(input);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
      CharSequence value = input.getText();


    }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        // Canceled.
      }
    });

    alert.show();
    // see http://androidsnippets.com/prompt-user-input-with-an-alertdialog 

}
```

Comment: You need to rethink the reason why you want to do "this". Maybe look into a singleton architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to change how I get context in the onCreate function. It is not this which is passed to the alertDialog function and works like a champ

context = this;

Answer (score 1):

to activate non static method, you must have an instance, otherwise - what will `this` refer to?

you can create a dummy instance and invoke userGuess() on it: `(new GuessingLettersActivity()).userGuess();`

however, if you realy do not need an instance, the `this` is not really needed, find a way not to use it, and declare `userGuess()` as static, it will be much more elegant.

if the instance is critical, there is a code smell here, how come you want to invoke userGuess() as static, but you need a specific instance? this can create a bug that will be caught only on later stages, so I suggest investigating it now.

Comment: I need this method to be called outside of the main activity. However it crashes when 'this' isn't used. getting the old value for Context and passing it to it crashes as well.

Answer (score -2):

The reason for this is because you are trying to make a static reference to a non-static method as the error suggests.  Change your method signature to the following:

```
public static void userGuess()
```

Comment: But it is not a static function? that first `AlertDialog` call wouldn't work in that case, would it?

Comment: you cant use a static function with 'this'

Comment: Doesn't allow this and old values for Context crashes the program.